# Trying to get the data from oracle database through logstash but data is not coming to elasticsearch

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to get the data of oracle database through `logstash` but data is not coming to `elasticsearch`. I am not sure where I missed it. I didn't see any error on `logstash` log file. Below are the `logstash` conf file.

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_validate_connection => "true" 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server:1521/db" 
    jdbc_user => "user" 
    jdbc_password => "pass" 
    jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/files/ojdbc7.jar" 
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
    jdbc_paging_enabled => "true" 
    schedule => "* * * * *" 
    statement_filepath => "/etc/logstash/files/keycount.sql" 
    use_column_value => "true" 
    tracking_column => "timestamp" 
    last_run_metadata_path => "/etc/logstash/files/.logstash_jdbc_last_run"
  }
} 
output { 
  elasticsearch { 
    hosts => "localhost:9200" 
    index => "keyinventory-%{+YYYY}" 
  } 
  stdout{ 
    codec => rubydebug 
  } 
}
```

Please, someone, help me.

Comment: Do you see the fetched data via stdout?

Comment: Can you please try adding the sql query to statement and try once. Just refer to this issue. you will get an idea https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-jdbc-query-issue/48725/12